# Soldier travels via interplanetary portal-like booth/kiosk

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

A short anthology story probably before 1980, certainly pre-Stargate.

Somewhere a booth has been found (or appeared) of unknown origin. It looks something like a telephone kiosk, big enough for one man, with some sort of mechanism to 'dial out'.

The authorities gather and it is decided to 'volunteer' a soldier to try it out. The soldier reluctantly enters the booth, dials something random and disappears.

The soldier is able to send messages back somehow. At first the messages are military reports. He is safe in a destination booth from where he can describe a new conventional world each time he dials. Some worlds are dangerous to human life but he is protected inside the booth.

In later messages he drops the formality as he visits more unearthly destinations. Eventually his communications become more spaced out and weird as he hasn't the words to describe the vast, unreal things he's experiencing.

Finally his messages stop. He never returns. The authorities send more soldiers. None of them want to come back either.

I feel the soldier having his consciousness expanded has a hippy-like vibe to it, which might indicate it's age. But it's a longshot.

Comment: Maybe Norman Spinrad? One or two of the stories in the collection The Last Hurrah of the Golden Horde suggest that this was a theme that interested him.

Comment: I wonder whether you might be conflating Simak's short story “Desertion” with something else.

Comment: @Barnaby Possibly I don't have that book but In sure Ive read it.

Comment: @AntonSherwoid No, I remember nothing about a dog. But that looks like an interesting read

Comment: Very very vaguely like Damon Knight's "Ticket To Anywhere ".